# AnyObject makes me nervous (Can't find an initialiser for type...)

Tags: ios, swift

Making default index = 0

```
    let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

    if !(defaults.objectForKey("LastIndex") != nil)
    {
        defaults.setObject(Int(0), forKey: "LastIndex")
    }
```

Then trying to compare this index with random number

```
    var randomIndex: Int = 0
    let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    let lastIndex: Int = Int(defaults.objectForKey("LastIndex"))

    while randomIndex != lastIndex
    {
        randomIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(phrasesArray.count)))
    }
```

but getting an error [image]

Comment: On which row do you get that error?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution – so simple that i even LOL'ed.

```
let lastIndex: Int = defaults.integerForKey("LastIndex")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store `Int` int `NSUserDefaults` you can do it directly this way:

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setInteger(YourIntValue, forKey: "LastIndex")
```

Let me correct some of your code. First of all look at this code:

```
let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

if !(defaults.objectForKey("LastIndex") != nil)
{
    defaults.setObject(Int(0), forKey: "LastIndex")
}
```

You are checking here that if there is value available for `LastIndex` or not but instead of trying that you can directly create a Int value with can directly read as `Int` from your memory with this code:

```
let abc = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().integerForKey("LastIndex")
println(abc)
```

With this code if there is no value for key `LastIndex` then it will set to `0` by default so it will print always `0` if there is nothing so you don't need to check if it is `nil` or not.

Now look at this code:

```
let lastIndex: Int = Int(defaults.objectForKey("LastIndex"))
```

Here you are reading values from that key where you are trying to casting it as `Int` but If you do it as I suggested you can directly get `Int` value form it so just make it simple like:

```
let lastIndex = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().integerForKey("LastIndex")
```

This will always return Int and if there is nothing set then it will be `0` by default.

And you can perform your action as you want:

```
while randomIndex != lastIndex {
        randomIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(phrasesArray.count)))
}
```

Hope it will help you.